# Can I set ultraChart axis minimum to 0 and still have automatic maximum?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, infragistics

I have a live datalogging program written in C# that can display an arbitrary number of parameters of arbitrary range. I need the Y axis `Maximum` to autoscale to accommodate the unpredictable nature of the incoming data, but I would like the `Minimum` of the axis to stay at zero to aid in readability, since it will otherwise jump around as the lowest value changes. I haven't been able to find anything here or on the Infragistics forum that addresses this issue.

The display is updated every 24 ms and the graphing alone takes up most of that, so I am looking for a way to set this up that doesn't require iterating over the whole `DataSet` manually searching for the maximum.

### What I need

- Set UltraChart axis minimum to zero (0).
- Have UltraChart axis maximum set to automatic (autoscale).
- Looking for a way that does not require iteration through the `DataSet` searching for a maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set the property `Chart.Data.ZeroAligned` to `true`.

You'll have to call `Chart.DataBind()` after setting the DataSource if you do this.

Comment: Well that explains why no one was asking for it; it's just a setting that I missed. That is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for letting me know!